# Making <ul> height same height as <div> and then <li> the sam height as that <ul>

Tags: html, css

So, basically I'm starting work on a portfolio website to showcase my work. I need to make it really functional and attractive, so would people who view the website know what I am capable of.

This is probably very basic for you guys, but in my code, the UL is inside the #nav-bar div and I would like to make it the same height, followed by the li items.

What I would like the end result to be is the bottom border of the li overlapping the bottom border of the whole div *exactly* (regardless of the screen resolution).

Hopefully, judging by my description and what you see from the code, you can figure out what I am trying to do.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
         margin: 0;
     }
     
     #nav-bar {
         width: 100%;
         height: 50px;
         background-color: rgb(40,40,40);
         border-bottom-style: solid;
         border-bottom-color: rgb(238,0,0);
         border-bottom-width: 7.5px;
     }
     
     ul#main-links {
         list-style: none;
         margin: 0;
        padding-top: 14px;
         padding-right: 50px;
         float: right;
        height: 42.5px;
        
     }
     
     ul#main-links li {
         display: inline;
         padding-right: 50px;
         
         border-bottom-style: solid;
         border-bottom-width: 7.5px;
         
         color: white;
         font-family: code;
         font-size: 18px;
         
     }
     
     @font-face {
         font-family: code;
         src: url(Arcon-Regular.otf);
     }
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Portfolio</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="nav-bar">
                    <ul id="main-links">
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Work</li>
                        <li>Contact</li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Like that - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1epydqr/)?

Comment: @AnonymousXD we're missing the contents of `stylesheet.css`. That's not how it will look in the end. 

@Chosen1 could you update Annonymous' fiddle by loading `stylesheet.css` as an external link? Thank you.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu, just get rid of that link rel and use internal CSS and it should work the same way.

Comment: Do you want those white border of your li to touch the red bar of your ul?

Comment: @Chosen1: that means that Anonymous' JSFiddle is what you need, right?

Comment: @AnonymousXD Sorry to be a pain, but the lines aren't overlapping exactly at different screen sizes. Try zooming in/out and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu, see my previous comment to him.

Comment: @undefinedtoken, I'd like the white bottom border to completely overlap the bottom border of the div, with nothing to spare. If that makes sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make columns equal heights - with nesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287088/make-columns-equal-heights-with-nesting). These elements are, or can be, block level elements which follow the same techniques found all over SO and the web.

Comment: @Chosen1 check my snippet below

Comment: You can use bootstrap and you got responsive `nav` https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/199/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(238, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-width: 7.5px;
  padding-top: 14px
}

ul#main-links {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 50px;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 7.5px solid transparent;
  display: block;
}

ul#main-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 7.5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: code;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: code;
  src: url(Arcon-Regular.otf);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="nav-bar">
    <ul id="main-links">
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Work</li>
      <li>Contact</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank your for your help.

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you describe what the issue, and what exactly you did.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that might be closer to your desired output:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(238, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-width: 8px;
}
ul#main-links {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 1px 0 0;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    float: right;
    height: 43px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
ul#main-links li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 50px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 8px;
    color: white;
    font-family: code;
    font-size: 18px;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: code;
    src: url(Arcon-Regular.otf);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="nav-bar">
    <ul id="main-links">
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Work</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've cleand it up a bit and updated. Now the `ul` is actually same height as the header. You're welcome.